# JQuery Toggle Button on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i need help in JQuery, i'm a beginner in programming.
    what i need is that when i clicked a specific button, the description will appear, but what  happens is that when i clicked a button they will all appear at once.  help please. thank you :)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").toggle(500);
  });
});
</script>


<body>


<?php
  include ("includes/connect.php"); 

  $query ="select * from jobshiring ";
  $run = mysql_query($query);

  while ($row=mysql_fetch_array ($run)) {
    $job_ID = $row['job_ID'];
    $job = $row['job'];
    $description = $row['description']; 
 ?> 

<table >
  <tr align="left"> 
    <td > <button> <?php echo $job;             ?>  </button></td>
    <td > <p>      <?php echo $description;     ?> </p>      </td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>    
</table>
```

Comment: Here is tutorial on [How to create JQuery plugin to convert radio buttons into toggle buttons](http://sgeek.org/jquery-toggle-button-plugin-for-sliding-toggle-switches-sswitch/) and [Here you can see demo](http://www.demos.sgeek.org/sswitch-jquery-plugin-demo/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change your button click handler to

```
$("button").click(function(){
   $(this).parent().next().find("p").toggle(500);
});
```

you need to traverse to paragraph in the next column